# Is programwith.com violating the Stack Overflow TOS and/or content licensing?

Tags: discussion, support, copycat-sites

I just came upon [this page](http://programwith.com/question_6027783_how-to-programmatically-kill-a-storm-topology), which is a pure copy of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20799178/507519). A quick look at the [main page](http://programwith.com/) of the site in question shows that this is *not* a unique example:

- [Copy](http://programwith.com/question_1944553_formatting-an-xml-file) - [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22431052/507519)
- [Copy](http://programwith.com/question_1944530_java-difference-null-vs-empty) - [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22431127/507519)
- ...

It seems that is a new site - parts of it are "in construction". That said, I cannot find a single sentence that attributes the content to Stack Overflow.

Am I missing something, or is this just a blatant (and illegal) rip-off?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: @apaul34208: seems like these guys are a bit more selective - they have not copied *everything*. That said, the procedure you linked to should be fine...

Comment: I notified the SE people and just got a reply that they are looking into it. Hopefully they will be able to address this issue without much difficulty...